# How to Get IP Conflict Message in Solaris 10

Tags: networking, ip, solaris

I am using Solaris 10, and SunStudio. I want to get the Error Message in my Program, when my system IP conflics with another one on the Network.
Please reply if some one know the solution.

Thanks
INAM

Comment: If your using SunStudio then I guess your programming in C. If you look at the [source](http://www.sfr-fresh.com/unix/privat/iputils-ss020927.tar.gz:a/iputils/arping.c) to arping you should be able to work out how to do it.

Comment: Before looking at the source code of arping suggested by lain you should know that it's GPLv2+ licensed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `arping <ip to check> -i device`. If the response is from another mac address as yours, then there is a conflict

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same on Solaris, but on Linux `arping -D ...` is used (*Duplicate address detection mode (DAD). See RFC2131, 4.4.1.*).

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu: Thanks, did not know this flag ;) On my debian lenny system (arping 2.07~pre1-2) the flag is lowercase

Comment: Fedora 13 uses the `arping` from iputils-20071127-12, not [this one](http://www.habets.pp.se/synscan/docs/arping.8.html) which seems to be the one used by Debian Lenny. By the way the exact command used by my *ifup-eth* script is `arping -q -c 2 -w 3 -D -I ${REALDEVICE} ${IPADDR}`.

Comment: arping is not bundled with Solaris 10.

Comment: @jilagre: I'm not familiar with the packages available in Solaris 10, but [arping](http://www.habets.pp.se/synscan/programs.php?prog=arping) should work on Solaris according to its author.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't wrote it won't work, just it isn't available out of the box. The "you can use" reply would have been better if a link to some place to get the binary, like sunfreeware.com had been provided, which is now done. eg for Solaris 10 on SPARC: ftp://ftp.sunfreeware.com/pub/freeware/sparc/10/arping-2.09-sol10-sparc-local.gz & ftp://ftp.sunfreeware.com/pub/freeware/sparc/10/libpcap-1.1.1-sol10-sparc-local.gz & http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc10.html#libgcc34

Comment: Yeah, I only wanted to clarify that it can run on Solaris. +1 for the links to the binaries.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about detecting if one of your IP addresses is already duplicate, you can look at the system messages (dmesg command output or /var/adm/messages* content) for a log of this type:

```
Sep 18 17:43:56 m10 ip: [ID 759807 kern.warning] WARNING: iwh0:1 has duplicate address 192.168.001.001 (in use by 00:22:75:12:34:56); disabled
```